# Fragment Activity Restarts when ACTION_VIEW Activity is started

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, onbackpressed

I am facing a strange Situation.

Suppose There is a Fragment Activity which is started with Fragment A. On Click of a Button on Fragment A, I replace the Fragment A by Fragment B and add the same to backstack. After that I click on a button on Fragment B to replace it from Fragment C. Now I have button on Fragment C and I do the following work on its clickL:

```
final String appPackageName = getActivity().getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        }
```

**Problem**: Everything goes fine, till I press back button. When I press back button, My fragment Activity is restarted i.e it shows the Fragment A. As per me it should show the Fragment C, from where I clicked the Button for Action_View.

Please help

Comment: what is launchMode mentioned in manifest?

Comment: Do you have a MainActivity which starts that fragments? If yes, did you try onBackPressed override method in MainActivity to handle back button clicks?

Comment: No Launchmode has been defined for that FragmentActivity. @RaviKant